# How to make girdview non editable or image button non editable in asp .net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to make the gridview not editable if uploaded date is not equal to todays date that means my gridview should be editable only for that particular day for this i have done in below way but after displaying the message i should make my image edit non clickable but i am unable to do that.How can i solve this

```
protected void GridView2_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        BindData();
        string date=DateTime.Now.ToString();
        string uploadeddate = Session["UploadedDate"].ToString();
        if (uploadeddate == date)
        {
            BtnExport.Visible = true;
            GridView2.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            BindData();
        }
        else
        {
            lblMsg.Visible = true; lblMsg.Text = "You Can Edit The Data Only On Uploaded Day!!!";

        }

    }


  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="Images/icon-edit.png" Height="32px" Width="32px"/>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="Images/update1.jpg"/>
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="Images/cancel.jpg"/>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

**i am trying to call image button id

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="Images/icon-edit.png" Height="32px" Width="32px"/>
```

imgbtnEdit.enabled=false; in c# but its not working**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindUsers();
        }
        string desi = Session["Role"].ToString();
        if (desi == "admin")
        {
            GridView2.Visible = true;
            GridView1.Visible = false;
            BtnExport.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            GridView2.Visible = false;
            GridView1.Visible = true;
            BtnExport.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How and where setting Session["UploadedDate"]

Comment: protected void BindData()
    {
        DataTable dt = adm.GetData();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string upldeddate = dt.Rows[i]["UploadedDate"].ToString();
                Session["UploadedDate"] = upldeddate;
            }
            //string uploadeddate = dt.Rows[0]["UploadedDate"].ToString();
            GridView2.DataSource = dt;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
    }   here i am getting the uploaded date from my database and keeping it is session

Comment: Can you put this code in the Question and remove it from comment. It's not readable here and not everyone will look at the comment.

Comment: As per your code in comment you are updating session variable in the for loop that means it will have the UpdateDate from the last row only. What if the updateDate of other row is not today's date? How are you handling it?

Comment: @nandinicharla Would you please put your code in the Question instead of comment? It is very hard to read it in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Enabled='<%# Eval("UploadedDate").Date == DateTime.Now.Date %>'` to image button

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="Images/icon-edit.png" Height="32px" Width="32px" Enabled='<%# Eval("UploadedDate").Date == DateTime.Now.Date %>'/>
```

And remove C# code for the same.

Explaination: Enable attribute will be set if `Eval("UploadedDate") == DateTime.Now.ToString()` condition match. Else it will be false.

**Make sure date format is proper, else format it manually.**

Comment: Can you please include some explanation about the code changes you suggested and how and why it should work?

Comment: Is it always disabled?

Comment: no what to do in my c# code  string date=DateTime.Now.ToString();
        string uploadeddate = Session["UploadedDate"].ToString();
        if (uploadeddate == date)
        {
            BtnExport.Visible = true;
            GridView2.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            BindData();
        }
        else
        {
            lblMsg.Visible = true; lblMsg.Text = "You Can Edit The Data Only On Uploaded Day!!!";
        } how should i modify this part of code

Comment: based on that condition only i am allowing to edit the gridview data if that is removed how can i get the uploaded date

Comment: That doesn't need to be checked in C# as I already done it in aspx

Comment: i am getting exception in aspx page that DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'UploadedDate'.

Comment: Add that column in data source

Comment: i should not show that column in gridview how to add it in datasource

Comment: Add it to datasource but not in itemtemplate

Comment: could you please show how to do that as i am new to this

Comment: Paste your page load

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindUsers();
        }
        string desi = Session["Role"].ToString();
        if (desi == "Supervisor")
        {
            GridView2.Visible = true;
            GridView1.Visible = false;
            lblUsers.Visible = true;
            BtnExport.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            GridView2.Visible = false;
            GridView1.Visible = true;
            lblUsers.Visible = false;
            BtnExport.Visible = false;
        }
    }

Comment: can anyone help me out as i am new to this

Comment: have you looked at my previous comment?

Comment: no could you please tell me how to do this i am unable to solve it i had pasted my page load code in my original post

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the `uploadedDate` in the session. If that field is part of the DataSource then you can use it in the GridView to decided if imagebutton should be enabled or disabled.

First of all you should simplify `BindData` method to as following.

```
protected void BindData() 
{ 
    DataTable dt = adm.GetData(); 
    GridView2.DataSource = dt; 
    GridView2.DataBind(); 
}
```

I see you are calling `BindUsers` method in Page_Load. You should call `BindData` method too in page_load if applicable.

You should also remove `GridView2_RowEditing` method from the code and remove `OnRowEditing="GridView2_RowEditing"` from GridView.

Now the `ItemTemplate` of ImageButton in the GridView should be changed to as following.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/icon-edit.png" Height="32px" Width="32px" Enabled='<%# Convert.ToDateTime( Eval("UploadedDate")).Date == DateTime.Now.Date %>'/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

This way, the imagebutton will be enabled or disabled based on the value of `UploadDate` of the current item which is bound to the GridViewRow of the GridView.

This should help you at least getting enabled/disabled imagebutton in the GridView. Please try and implement this approach completely and test it and tell us if it's working or not.

If it's not working please provide details how it's not working and what error or unexpected behavior your are getting.